# udisksctl unmount with wildcard possible?

Tags: 18.04, udisks

I use Ubuntu bionic. Is it possible to umount with udisksctl unmount with wildcards? Short story, when I plug in my backupdrive a user systemd.service start my backskript. when the backup is ready I have to unmount every patition with `udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdc1` and so on. I can nothing find in the manpages. I want to create on desktop a starter to umount all partition of my backudrive at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found no way to make it over udisksctl. I make a starter with `Exec=umount /media/my_username/*`